# get facebook likes count in iphone-sdk

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I don't want to show Like button... I just want to get the Number of count that has been liked for particular link... Just Cont.. No like button No dialogue Nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a simple url request to the Graph API:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[FULL URL]

Example:
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.stackoverflow.com

Edit: (an example with "LIKES")
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/
```

Awesome, isn't it?

Comment: It depends on the type of content. Stackoverflow cannot be "Liked", so it has no "Like" count. If your website has a "Like" button, it will indeed have a count. For example: http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to mention that if your URL has any question marks or ampersands in it, you will need to use a different notation:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=[PROPERLY ENCODED FULL URL]
```

For example:
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://mydomain.com/viewsomething.php%3Fid%3D2

Comment: Hi,
Just a quick question,can we get number of likes of a picture or a link posted over facebook..?
Please help..
Thanks