# How to show likes count for Facebook Pages on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-ios-sdk

I would like to show number of likes page facebook.
i don't need the like button, only show the real number page have.

I already li any tutorial but i doesn't found  this specifies function.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740068/get-facebook-likes-count-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : (for example)

```
NSData *Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"]];
NSJSONSerialization *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:Data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSString *totalLikes = [json valueForKey:@"likes"]
DLog(@"%@",totalLikes);
```